# Help Needed to convert a C# List into a proper format

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I'm a bit new to C# and need help with the following problem

I have a List ticker which contains following values in it

```
ticker[0] =1
ticker[1] = 122
ticker[2] = 321
.....
ticker[n] = n  // where n is some random number
```

Now the problem is that I need to create an object List which looks like

```
keys:[[1,66],[122,66],[321,66],.....,[n,66]]
```

Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance 
--P

Comment: "[1,66]" is this should be a string? Why it called Keys? Are you need some kind of dictionary?

Comment: It's unclear (to me) how your target list should be structured, i.e. what does [1,66] mean? Where does the 66 come from?

Comment: Can you explain further and put into more specific context? "Ticker" doesn't mean anything. Nor does 1, 122, 321, 66, etc. I don't understand what you're trying to do. What is "proper format"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create an array of arrays:

```
int[][] keys = ticker.Select(n => new int[] { n, 66} ).ToArray();
```

If you want to create a string:

```
string s = "keys:[" + String.Join(",", ticker.Select(n => "[" + n.ToString() + ",66]")) + "]";
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy:

```
var pairs = ticker.Select(x=>new[]{x,66}).ToList();
```

`pairs` will be an list of 2-element integer arrays, where each element in your original array is paired with a second value of 66.

You could also use the same statement to create a Tuple (in .NET 4.0) of two integers:

```
var pairs = ticker.Select(x=>new Tuple<int,int>(x,66)).ToList();
```

This is a little more O/O; you access the first and second values of the pair using `.Value1` and `.Value2` instead of `[0]` and `[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Using Linq, if you want to map the value to the index.

```
ticker.Select((val, index) => new[] { val, index }).ToList();
```

If you literally want the number 66 after each item:

```
ticker.Select(val => new[] { val, 66 }).ToList();
```

That will create a list of arrays, each the pair of values you wanted.